# How can I find the current DNS server?

Tags: windows, delphi, networking, dns

I'm using Delphi and need to get the current Windows DNS server IP address so I can do a lookup. What function should I call to find it? The only solution I have right now does an ipconfig/all to get it, which is horrible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a nice one using the function GetNetworkParams().Seems to work quite good.
You can find it here:
http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=2452

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to know what is DNS server to do a lookup?

[Here](http://delphi.about.com/od/networking/l/aa103100a.htm) is a solution how to get a IP address using 2 functions: GetHostName and GetHostByName. I assume the GetHostByName function does the lookup you need for you, or am I wrong?

Comment: I'm wanting to get the DNS server so I can do an MX lookup. The code you link to seems to show how to find your own IP?

Comment: Yes. I assumed you wanted just a name->IP lookup, so gave you the GetHostByName function :)

Answer (score 0):

See *[GetNetowrkParams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365968(VS.85).aspx)* method (Platform SDK: IP Helper)